ESLint Import Issue in Turborepo with Vue and Nuxt
I'm currently working with Turborepo and Vue/Nuxt, following the example project from this GitHub link.
I ran the following command to create my project:
npx create-turbo@latest -e with-vue-nuxt

After executing the command, I set up the project structure within the apps folder, which looks like this:
apps
├── docs
├── web
    ├── public
    ├── src
        ├── components
            ├── test.ts
            ├── test11.vue
        ├── app.vue
        ├── main.ts
    ├── .eslintrc.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── vite.config.ts

When I try to import a component inside app.vue, like so:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Page } from 'ui';
import Test11 from '@/components/test11.vue';
</script>

I get the following ESLint error:
eslint error
ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@/components/test11.vue'. (import/no-unresolved)

I haven't made any modifications to the tsconfig or eslint settings. Imports in the packages directory work just fine, but imports inside the apps directory throw this import/no-unresolved error.
I could disable the rule using the following option:
"import/no-unresolved": "off",

But I would prefer a proper solution to resolve this issue without disabling the rule. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?
Thank you!


Please, provide the relevant configs (eslint and ts). FWIW it doesn't seem that the rule has practical need. You'll have an error for unresolved import both in IDE and during build without it

Try to run the "npm run prepare"
